# Can a list of $m+1$ polynomials with degree at most $m$ be linearly independent if at least two elements of the list have the same degree?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Given the vector space of polynomials with degree at most $m$, can a list of $m + 1$ polynomials in this vector space be linearly dependent if at least two of the polynomials have the same degree?

It seems the converse is proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253644/about-polynomials-if-there-are-no-two-polynomials-of-the-same-degree-in-s-th) but I can't seem to be able to derive the question here, even though it seems probably true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For example, consider the case $m = 1$ and the set $$\{x, x + 1\} .$$

Comment: Oh of course! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful.